# Ractive radio button binding - preserve name

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I understand that to bind a ractive variable to a radio-button, the easiest way is to have

```
<input type="radio" name="{{myVar}}" value="1" checked>
```

in the template, but the curly brackets on the name persist into the html.  Is there a clever way to get it to output

```
<input type="radio" name="myVar" value="1" checked>
```

in the html, so I don't have to alter the form-handling?  I've tried some logic along the lines of

```
<input type="radio" name="myVar" value="1" {{#myVar==1}}checked{{/myVar==1}}
```

but that doesn't bind.

Also, less importantly, is there a way to bind it as a numeric value, as if I have

```
data:{myVar:1}
```

Then the button doesn't get checked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ractive adds the curly braces to input names to guard against the (highly unlikely) possibility of a conflict between `name='{{myVar}}'` and `name='myVar'` - no other reason. The binding is created when the element is rendered; what the name becomes after that is irrelevant.

So although there's no way to prevent the curly braces being added in the first place, you can certainly change them afterwards:

```
ractive.findAll('input[type="radio"]').forEach( function(input) {
  input.name = input.name.replace('{{','').replace('}}','');
});
```

If you were creating a component with `Ractive.extend()` this could be part of the `init()` method, for example.

It shouldn't have a problem with numeric values, at least as of the last released version ([0.3.9](https://github.com/RactiveJS/Ractive/tree/master/release/0.3.9)) and current development version ([0.4.0](https://github.com/RactiveJS/Ractive/tree/0.4.0/build)). See this fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/7qQZ8/

Comment: Thanks for that - and for developing the library.  I've now realised that my problem is deeper!  As I'm creating a series of radio groups, through a loop, the 'myVar' name actually gets changed to something along the lines of '{{parent.0.myVar}}'.  I'm going to have to change my form handling logic to deal with this (or take your findall suggestion).  I might look at hacking the original to mimic the checkbox approach - I'd really like `<input type="radio" name="realName" value="A" checked='{{myVarTakesValuesABC}}'>`  - Any reason this approach wasn't used originally?

Comment: Almost there - if I change the _value_ method of `CheckedBinding.prototype` to return `this.node.value` if the node is of radio type, then the binding almost works as I wanted in my previous comment - but the _update_ method means the interface gets a bit out of sync, at least in chrome [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VK6qK/5)

Comment: And adding this at line 3936 of v0.3.9 seems to enable correct updating of _checked_ attributes in a radioset `if (this.lcName === 'checked') {
     this.update = updateRadioName;
     return this.update();
  }`

Comment: just as further reference, you can always add an `<input type="hidden" name="myVar" value="{{myVar}}">` if you're problem is keeping things consistent with server side form handling

Comment: I use parsleyJS to do form validation and the curly braces break it. Throws a syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: I don't think it's possible to do what you want.

Ractive handles radio buttons differently than simple HTML markup. It assumes that you're going to want to retrieve which radio button is set using a simple variable, and it relies on the `name` attribute to do that. Specifically, it expects you to set the `name` attribute to the same specific variable (e.g. `"{{myVar}}"`) in all radio buttons in a group. It will then automatically set that variable to the `value` attribute of whichever individual radio button is selected.

For example, if you have the following code:

```
    <label><input type='radio' name='{{myVar}}' value='1' checked> 1</label>
    <label><input type='radio' name='{{myVar}}' value='2'        > 2</label>
    <label><input type='radio' name='{{myVar}}' value='3'        > 3</label>
    <p>The selected value is {{myVar}}.</p>
```

Then Ractive will automatically update the `<p>` with information on whatever radio button is selected.

Comment: Thanks for that - I was rather worried that it wouldn't be possible.  I'm using it as you had in your code, and had a bit of javascript that intercepted the data before it was submitted, to remove the braces from the fieldnames, but wanted to get rid of the hack.  Also, I'm generating multiple radio-sets through a loop, so would have liked to have `name='myVar[{{i}}]'` but that's not going to be compatible with how Ractive binds the name.

Comment: @GavinKelly would this approach work for generating multiple radio sets? http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/dg8Kd/

Comment: @RichHarris this works, but the problem is that every set must have the same amount of radios. Do you have an other idea?